# html2canvas and Canvas2Image, want to get screenshot bigger than resize image

Tags: javascript, html, image

I want to get bigger size of resized image through html2canvas and Canvas2Image:

Assume my resize image (Actual 800*800px) is 300*300px and i want to get screen shot of that actual image which is 800*800px not of resized.

Now its getting blurred because its resizing 300px image to 800px image.

My JavaScript code mentioned below

```
html2canvas($(".meme-img"), {
          onrendered: function(canvas) {
             var img = Canvas2Image.convertToImage(canvas, 800, 800);

             console.log(img);
          }
      });
```

Comment: So you want it to add definition to your image ? That would be great if something like that could exist... No need for microscope anymore, we could go to the infinitely small with a simple SD webcam. Joke aside, you'll have to make your browser render what you want to capture at that size before converting it.

Comment: `html2canvas` doesn't take a screenshot - it creates an image from the CSS of the element.  To avoid blurring you would need to re-size the element before running the function - and then restore it to the initial size once the 'image' has been captured.